# Field is being sliced when using solr pivot

Tags: solr

I have the following query:

```
/search?facet.pivot=host&facet.pivot=name&facet=on&indent=on&q=&rows=10&start=0&wt=json
```

and this is the response header

```
"responseHeader":{
    "zkConnected":true,
    "status":0,
    "QTime":420,
    "params":{
      "q":"",
      "facet.pivot":["host",
        "name"],
      "indent":"on",
      "start":"0",
      "rows":"10",
      "facet":"on",
      "wt":"json",
      "_":"1512394263979"}}
```

The host part is always a domain `stackoverflow.com` or `google.com`,  While the name is a full name something like `Stack Exchange Inc` or `Google Inc.` so using this query the results is like this:

```
"response":{"numFound":2,"start":0,"maxScore":56.923157,"docs":[
      {
        "host":"google.com",
        "name":"Google Inc."},
      {
        "url":"stackoverflow.com",
        "name":"Stack Exchange Inc."},
      ]
 },
 "facet_counts":{
"facet_queries":{},
"facet_fields":{},
"facet_ranges":{},
"facet_intervals":{},
"facet_heatmaps":{},
"facet_pivot":{
  "host":[{
      "field":"host",
      "value":"google.com",
      "count":1},
    {
      "field":"host",
      "value":"stackoverflow.com",
      "count":1}]
 },
 "facet_pivot":{
  "name":[{
      "field":"name",
      "value":"Inc.",
      "count":2
    {
      "field":"name",
      "value":"Google",
      "count":1},
    {
      "field":"name",
      "value":"Stack",
      "count":1},
    {
      "field":"name",
      "value":"Exchange",
      "count":1}]
 },
 ....
```

The question is how can i match the whole name? so the pivot will be

```
"facet_pivot":{
      "name":[{
          "field":"name",
          "value":"Google Inc.",
          "count":1},
        {
          "field":"name",
          "value":"Stack Exchange Inc.",
          "count":1}]
     },
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. `name` field type is `text` which is being tokenized so it will be sliced -by spaces- into multi-words. The solution would be to copy the name field to another field with type 'string' and then `facet.pivot=name_str` would solve the issue

More explanation in this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/17915897/2724879